# Table Detection Algorithms

Tags: pdf, information-extraction

### Context

I have a bunch of PDF files. Some of them are scanned (i.e. images). They consist of text + pictures + tables.

I want to turn the tables into CSV files.

### Current Plan:

1) Run Tesseract OCR to get text of all the documents.

2) ??? Run some type of Table Detection Algorithm ???

3) Extract the rows / columns / cells, and the text in them.

### Question:

Is there some standard "Table Extraction Algorithm" to use?

Thanks!

Comment: I replaced the inappropriate tag [tag:data-mining] with the much more appropriate tags [tag:pdf] and [tag:information-extraction]. This question clearly is about extracting information from PDF files, not statistical analysis of data (as done in data mining).

Answer (score 2):

Abbyy Fine Reader includes table detection and will be the easiest approach.  It can scan, import PDF', TIFF's etc.  You will also be able to manually adjust the tables and columns when the auto detection fails.

www.abbyy.com  - You should be able to download a trial version and you will also find the OCR results are much more accurate than Tesseract which will also save you a lot of time.

Trying to write something yourself will be hit and miss as there are too many different types of tables to cope with.  ie.  with lines, without lines, shaded, multiple lines, different alignments, headers, footers etc..

Good luck.